# Scraping specific checkbox values using Python

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to analyze the data on this website: [website](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/forecastedTransferCapacitiesMonthAhead/show)

I want to scrape a couple of countries such as BZN|PT - BZN|ES and BZN|RO - BZN|BG

I tried for forecastedTransferCapacitiesMonthAhead the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/forecastedTransferCapacitiesMonthAhead/show')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

tran_month = soup.find('table', id='dv-datatable').findAll('tr')

for price in tran_month:
    print(''.join(price.get_text("|", strip=True).split()))
```

But I only get the preselected country. How can I pass my arguments so that I can select the countries that I want? Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing a crucial part - i.e., the parameters which inform the requests, like import/export and from/to countries and types.

In order to solve the issue, below you might find a code built on yours, which uses the GET + parameters function of `requests`. To run the complete code, you should find out the complete list of parameters per country.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

payload = { # this is the dictionary whose values can be changed for the request
    'name' : '',
    'defaultValue' : 'false',
    'viewType' : 'TABLE',
    'areaType' : 'BORDER_BZN',
    'atch' : 'false',
    'dateTime.dateTime' : '01.05.2020 00:00|UTC|MONTH',
    'border.values' : 'CTY|10YPL-AREA-----S!BZN_BZN|10YPL-AREA-----S_BZN_BZN|10YDOM-CZ-DE-SKK',
    'direction.values' : ['Export', 'Import']
    }

page = requests.get('https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/forecastedTransferCapacitiesMonthAhead/show',
                     params = payload) # GET request + parameters

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

tran_month = soup.find('table', id='dv-datatable').findAll('tr')

for price in tran_month: # print all values, row by row (date, export and import)
    print(price.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @crap.py. What if I wish to get more than one option for border.values (more than one border), and I wish to get both directions. As I said in the first comment BZN|PT - BZN|ES, BZN|RO - BZN|BG.

Comment: As I hinted at in the answer, you should change the 'border.values' value within the dictionary, most likely within a for loop. In order to find which values to loop, I suggest you to inspect the page and take note of all available values triggered by clicking on the country tickbox. P.S. crap.py is by far the best misspelling of my account name I can think of, thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks. I can't breath from laughing about the misspelling.

Comment: You're welcome. If you ended up using the answer, consider to mark it as accepted for future references.

Comment: P.s. you might already know that, but the transparency platform of entso-e follows an open data policy which involves (on top of the website) the access to an FTP server storing the universe of entso-e data. See https://entsoe.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000173266-Overview-of-data-download-options-on-Transparency-Platform fo further info